# Not authorizing sandbox in VS code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, authorization

I am getting error while authorizing sandbox in VS code. Earlier I was successfully authorized old sandbox but now it is giving error. After Users\PJ20912 I am not able to see path in my computer.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

> 10:02:12.469 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias Dev1s152
> --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername '"****C:\Users\PJ20912**AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin****..\7.209.6-8ba3197\bin\sfdx.cmd**"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
> or batch file. 10:02:13.178 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias
> Dev1s152 --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com
> --setdefaultusername  ended with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the sfdx.cmd file from the sfdx/client folder. On Windows, its probably located in `"C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin"`. If its installed it in a different location, you probably already have it in your PATH variable, so you can get the file location from there.

After you've deleted it, restart your computer and try authorizing in VS Code again.

Started seeing this issue after the VS Code update to v1.81, but my non-sfdx extensions did not have any problems, so its still unclear to me at this point what the cause was.